# How to configure x-axis and manually set start/end time for d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Example here: erics-health.appspot.com

Currently, the x-axis ticks are set by looking at max/min. However, I'm trying to be able to define the min and max of the axis. I only want to display data from 8PM to 10AM. I may have data outside of these ranges but I don't want it to show up in the chart.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [
  {date : "22:34:00", close : 1.55145},
  {date : "22:40:00", close : 0.7433334},
  {date : "22:46:00", close : 0.74002784},
  {date : "22:51:00", close : 0.8358186},
  {date : "22:57:00", close : 0.8453624},
  {date : "23:03:00", close : 1.1331508},
  {date : "23:09:00", close : 1.0483232},
  {date : "23:15:00", close : 0.3787978},
  {date : "23:21:00", close : 0.028143013},
  {date : "23:27:00", close : 0.02481636},
  {date : "23:32:00", close : 0.024784887},
  {date : "23:38:00", close : 0.028799044},
  {date : "23:44:00", close : 0.028170206},
  {date : "23:50:00", close : 0.025131205},
  {date : "23:56:00", close : 0.11552841},
  {date : "0:02:00", close : 0.29101047},
  {date : "0:07:00", close : 0.29101828},
  {date : "0:13:00", close : 0.15327774},
  {date : "0:19:00", close : 0.12934181},
  {date : "0:25:00", close : 0.15818097},
  {date : "0:31:00", close : 0.14875501},
  {date : "0:37:00", close : 0.14916791},
  {date : "0:43:00", close : 0.08311816},
  {date : "0:48:00", close : 0.3359427},
  {date : "0:54:00", close : 0.12637037},
  {date : "1:00:00", close : 0.02719137},
  {date : "1:06:00", close : 0.027614024},
  {date : "1:12:00", close : 0.030077167},
  {date : "1:18:00", close : 0.031363245},
  {date : "1:23:00", close : 0.024196008},
  {date : "1:29:00", close : 0.10927427},
  {date : "1:35:00", close : 0.066115},
  {date : "1:41:00", close : 0.09814477},
  {date : "1:47:00", close : 0.62218755},
  {date : "1:53:00", close : 0.6253947},
  {date : "1:58:00", close : 0.15986814},
  {date : "2:04:00", close : 0.15649848},
  {date : "2:10:00", close : 0.083005086},
  {date : "2:16:00", close : 0.027678054},
  {date : "2:22:00", close : 0.025061065},
  {date : "2:28:00", close : 0.027554804},
  {date : "2:34:00", close : 0.14941628},
  {date : "2:39:00", close : 0.14944676},
  {date : "2:45:00", close : 0.026169432},
  {date : "2:51:00", close : 0.22071813},
  {date : "2:57:00", close : 0.057087168},
  {date : "3:03:00", close : 0.05648345},
  {date : "3:09:00", close : 0.05211234},
  {date : "3:14:00", close : 0.3934766},
  {date : "3:20:00", close : 0.39347196},
  {date : "3:26:00", close : 0.90130115},
  {date : "3:32:00", close : 0.90089816},
  {date : "3:38:00", close : 0.03359231},
  {date : "3:44:00", close : 0.18505707},
  {date : "3:49:00", close : 0.026783684},
  {date : "3:55:00", close : 0.13720763},
  {date : "4:01:00", close : 0.09140902},
  {date : "4:07:00", close : 0.031246372},
  {date : "4:13:00", close : 0.024439864},
  {date : "4:19:00", close : 0.27394825},
  {date : "4:25:00", close : 0.2739199},
  {date : "4:30:00", close : 0.19392326},
  {date : "4:36:00", close : 0.23098093},
  {date : "4:42:00", close : 0.15341641},
  {date : "4:48:00", close : 0.033248696},
  {date : "4:54:00", close : 0.026490664},
  {date : "5:00:00", close : 0.113400206},
  {date : "5:05:00", close : 0.11344097},
  {date : "5:11:00", close : 0.024459623},
  {date : "5:17:00", close : 0.17521942},
  {date : "5:23:00", close : 0.13070703},
  {date : "5:29:00", close : 0.055239253},
  {date : "5:35:00", close : 0.032200478},
  {date : "5:40:00", close : 0.027074447},
  {date : "5:46:00", close : 0.022963678},
  {date : "5:52:00", close : 0.07365599},
  {date : "5:58:00", close : 0.0737282},
  {date : "6:04:00", close : 0.027280098},
  {date : "6:10:00", close : 0.02937219},
  {date : "6:16:00", close : 1.0709208},
  {date : "6:21:00", close : 1.3994151},
  {date : "6:27:00", close : 0.91793543},
  {date : "6:33:00", close : 1.9869174},
  {date : "6:39:00", close : 0.7651712},
  {date : "6:45:00", close : 0.70828897},
  {date : "6:51:00", close : 3.8604095}
];


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 1920 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;

    data = data.map(function(datum)
{
  var bundle = datum;

  bundle.date  = parseDate(datum.date);
  bundle.close = datum.close;

  return bundle;
});


var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
//  .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I %p'))
//  .tickValues([]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  //x.domain([d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date; }), d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.date; })]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/blakedietz/M6ZML/

Next time, please supply the data or data similar to that of the data that you are using in your example.  I had to hunt down the form of the data on your website and I had to reformat it to a in browser form due to the fact that you were using `d3.csv()` which requires an ajax call.  To ensure that your questions can be answered properly, create an example that is self contained in order to make sure that those who are reading the problem don't have to do extra work as I had to.

This code will get you headed in the right direction.  Basically, your only problem is that you need to set the domain of the corresponding scale.  This is done by using the following line of code:

```
x.domain([start,end]).clamp(true);
```

From here no matter the values that are given to the scale, only values that are within the range will be mapped to the visible area in the chart that uses the scales.  Do note `.clamp(true)`.

**From the d3 api**

> scale.clamp([boolean])
>
> If boolean is specified, enables or disables clamping accordingly. By
>   default, clamping is disabled, such that if a value outside the input
>   domain is passed to the scale, the scale may return a value outside
>   the output range through linear extrapolation. For example, with the
>   default domain and range of [0,1], an input value of 2 will return an
>   output value of 2. If clamping is enabled, the normalized domain
>   parameter t is clamped to the range [0,1], such that the return value
>   of the scale is always within the scale's output range. If boolean is
>   not specified, returns whether or not the scale currently clamps
>   values to within the output range.

**Corresponding jsfiddle code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

var data = [
  {date : "22:34:00", close : 1.55145},
  {date : "22:40:00", close : 0.7433334},
  {date : "22:46:00", close : 0.74002784},
  {date : "22:51:00", close : 0.8358186},
  {date : "22:57:00", close : 0.8453624},
  {date : "23:03:00", close : 1.1331508},
  {date : "23:09:00", close : 1.0483232},
  {date : "23:15:00", close : 0.3787978},
  {date : "23:21:00", close : 0.028143013},
  {date : "23:27:00", close : 0.02481636},
  {date : "23:32:00", close : 0.024784887},
  {date : "23:38:00", close : 0.028799044},
  {date : "23:44:00", close : 0.028170206},
  {date : "23:50:00", close : 0.025131205},
  {date : "23:56:00", close : 0.11552841},
  {date : "0:02:00", close : 0.29101047},
  {date : "0:07:00", close : 0.29101828},
  {date : "0:13:00", close : 0.15327774},
  {date : "0:19:00", close : 0.12934181},
  {date : "0:25:00", close : 0.15818097},
  {date : "0:31:00", close : 0.14875501},
  {date : "0:37:00", close : 0.14916791},
  {date : "0:43:00", close : 0.08311816},
  {date : "0:48:00", close : 0.3359427},
  {date : "0:54:00", close : 0.12637037},
  {date : "1:00:00", close : 0.02719137},
  {date : "1:06:00", close : 0.027614024},
  {date : "1:12:00", close : 0.030077167},
  {date : "1:18:00", close : 0.031363245},
  {date : "1:23:00", close : 0.024196008},
  {date : "1:29:00", close : 0.10927427},
  {date : "1:35:00", close : 0.066115},
  {date : "1:41:00", close : 0.09814477},
  {date : "1:47:00", close : 0.62218755},
  {date : "1:53:00", close : 0.6253947},
  {date : "1:58:00", close : 0.15986814},
  {date : "2:04:00", close : 0.15649848},
  {date : "2:10:00", close : 0.083005086},
  {date : "2:16:00", close : 0.027678054},
  {date : "2:22:00", close : 0.025061065},
  {date : "2:28:00", close : 0.027554804},
  {date : "2:34:00", close : 0.14941628},
  {date : "2:39:00", close : 0.14944676},
  {date : "2:45:00", close : 0.026169432},
  {date : "2:51:00", close : 0.22071813},
  {date : "2:57:00", close : 0.057087168},
  {date : "3:03:00", close : 0.05648345},
  {date : "3:09:00", close : 0.05211234},
  {date : "3:14:00", close : 0.3934766},
  {date : "3:20:00", close : 0.39347196},
  {date : "3:26:00", close : 0.90130115},
  {date : "3:32:00", close : 0.90089816},
  {date : "3:38:00", close : 0.03359231},
  {date : "3:44:00", close : 0.18505707},
  {date : "3:49:00", close : 0.026783684},
  {date : "3:55:00", close : 0.13720763},
  {date : "4:01:00", close : 0.09140902},
  {date : "4:07:00", close : 0.031246372},
  {date : "4:13:00", close : 0.024439864},
  {date : "4:19:00", close : 0.27394825},
  {date : "4:25:00", close : 0.2739199},
  {date : "4:30:00", close : 0.19392326},
  {date : "4:36:00", close : 0.23098093},
  {date : "4:42:00", close : 0.15341641},
  {date : "4:48:00", close : 0.033248696},
  {date : "4:54:00", close : 0.026490664},
  {date : "5:00:00", close : 0.113400206},
  {date : "5:05:00", close : 0.11344097},
  {date : "5:11:00", close : 0.024459623},
  {date : "5:17:00", close : 0.17521942},
  {date : "5:23:00", close : 0.13070703},
  {date : "5:29:00", close : 0.055239253},
  {date : "5:35:00", close : 0.032200478},
  {date : "5:40:00", close : 0.027074447},
  {date : "5:46:00", close : 0.022963678},
  {date : "5:52:00", close : 0.07365599},
  {date : "5:58:00", close : 0.0737282},
  {date : "6:04:00", close : 0.027280098},
  {date : "6:10:00", close : 0.02937219},
  {date : "6:16:00", close : 1.0709208},
  {date : "6:21:00", close : 1.3994151},
  {date : "6:27:00", close : 0.91793543},
  {date : "6:33:00", close : 1.9869174},
  {date : "6:39:00", close : 0.7651712},
  {date : "6:45:00", close : 0.70828897},
  {date : "6:51:00", close : 3.8604095}
];


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
     width = 1920 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;

data = data.map(function(datum)
{
  var bundle = datum;

  bundle.date  = parseDate(datum.date);
  bundle.close = datum.close;

  return bundle;
});

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var start = new Date(1900, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0);
var end = new Date(1900, 0, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0);

var uniqueDays = [];

data.forEach(function(element)
{
  var day = element.date.getDay();

  var isUnique = checkIfUnique(day);

  if (uniqueDays.length == 0 || isUnique)
  {
    uniqueDays.push(day);
  } 

  function checkIfUnique(day)
  {
    var flag = true;
    uniqueDays.forEach(function(element)
    {
      if (element == day)
      {
        flag = false;
      }
    })

    return flag;
  }
});


var xDomain = [start,end];

  x.domain(xDomain).clamp(true);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

</script>
</body>
```

In correspondence to the recent comments:

That's because your data is a bit messed up.  If you remove the following range of data:

```
{date : "22:34:00", close : 1.55145},   {date : "22:40:00", close :
0.7433334},   {date : "22:46:00", close : 0.74002784},   {date : "22:51:00", close : 0.8358186},   {date : "22:57:00", close :
0.8453624},   {date : "23:03:00", close : 1.1331508},   {date : "23:09:00", close : 1.0483232},   {date : "23:15:00", close :
0.3787978},   {date : "23:21:00", close : 0.028143013},   {date : "23:27:00", close : 0.02481636},   {date : "23:32:00", close :
0.024784887},   {date : "23:38:00", close : 0.028799044},   {date : "23:44:00", close : 0.028170206},   {date : "23:50:00", close :
0.025131205},   {date : "23:56:00", close : 0.11552841},   {date : "0:02:00", close : 0.29101047},
```

There will be nothing in the range.  Furthermore if you add the following data you will see data within the range.

```
  {date : "8:20:00", close : 3.8604095},
  {date : "8:22:00", close : 5.04095},
  {date : "9:20:00", close : 3.8604095},
  {date : "9:22:00", close : 5.04095},
  {date : "10:22:00", close : 1.04095},
```

I think that you're missing the whole notion of domain.  If your function does not have any information that's in you the range of your domain of interest then you won't display that information.

However in your case you have information that spans outside of the range which is also on the same day. The range from 22:--:-- to 23:--:-- is causing a linear interpolation to happen from 6:51:00 to 22:--:--. You need to determine when data will be separated into each day, otherwise data will be *wrapped* when you're moving from day to day information.

Comment: Thanks Arete and apologies for not pasting the code! So I've used your suggestions but now it doesn't seem to post the y values? It just draws a line seeming from the first y-value at the minimum x to the last y-value at the maximum x.